# Adding a 'check username' to registration form PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, registration

Please could someone give me some much needed direction...

I have a registration form, however I need to add a condition that if the username is already in the table, then a message will appear. I have a had a few goes except it just keeps adding to the SQL table.

Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my current code:

Thanks in advance!

```
    <?php
    session_start();session_destroy();
    session_start();
    $regname = $_GET['regname'];
    $passord = $_GET['password'];
    if($_GET["regname"] && $_GET["regemail"] && $_GET["regpass1"] && $_GET["regpass2"] )
    {
        if($_GET["regpass1"]==$_GET["regpass2"])
{
    $host="localhost";
    $username="xxx";
    $password="xxx";
    $conn=  mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("xxx",$conn);
    $sql="insert into users (name,email,password) values('$_GET[regname]','$_GET[regemail]','$_GET[regpass1]')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    print "<h1>you have registered sucessfully</h1>";

    print "<a href='login_index.php'>go to login page</a>";
}
    else print "passwords don't match";
    }
    else print"invaild input data";

    ?>
```

Comment: Give up on this code until you've learned about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and why your code is downright dangerous.

Comment: Almost nobody learning the very basics is interested in SQL injection or other security issues.

Comment: Just define the field `name` as `UNIQUE` in SQL and listen to the error when trying to insert

Comment: +10 for SQL injection point! Starters for 10 - there is nowhere you are checking if it already exists, I would advise you don't use GET, no idea why you are starting then destroying then starting the session and you have a type in $passord=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User *kingkero* offered a good approach. You could modify your table so that the *username* field is **UNIQUE** and therefore the table cannot contain rows with duplicate usernames.

However, if you cannot modify the table or for other reasons want to choose a different approach, you can first try to run a select on the table, check the results and act accordingly:

```
$result=mysql_query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE name="'.$_GET['regname'].'"');
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

You can then check `$row` if it contains the username:

```
if($row['name']==$_GET['regname'])
```

If this statement returns true, then you can show the user a message and tell him to pick a different username.

**Please note**

Using variables that come directly from the client (or browser) such as what might be stored in `$_GET['regname']` and using them to build your SQL statement is considered unsafe (see [the Wikipedia article on SQL-Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

You can use

```
$regname=mysql_escape_string($_GET['regname'])
```

to make sure that its safe.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is some chaos on the second line:

```
session_start();session_destroy();
session_start();
```

Why you doing it? Just one `session_start();` needed.

Then you can find users by simple SQL query:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$regname'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //...echo your message here
}
```

When you got it, I suggest you to **rewrite your code** with use of PDO and param data binding, in order to prevent SQL injections and using of obsolete functions.